# Navigation in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Good afternoon, I'm creating an "Areas" page on my Wordpress website with a page structure like this;

```
Home About Us Areas
- Wiltshire
-- Salisbury
-- Wilton
- Hampshire
-- Andover
-- Portsmouth
```

I'm looking for a way to generate all the links on the areas page with the parent of the town being the Title!

For example

```
<h2>Wiltshire</h2>
<ul>
   <li><a href>Salisbury</a></li>
   <li><a href>Wilton</a></li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to generate these links within Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the pages and then create a custom [menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus). Once registered [add the menu items](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide). Most themes have a navigation menu up the top. You can find the code which registers it in `functions.php` of the theme directory. If your pages have different functionality to regular pages, consider registering a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and adding those instead of regular pages.

Answer (score 0):

The theme which you use should support the Menu if you intend to use the Menu options in the Wordpress dashboard, check the [Menu_User_Guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)

If you wish to write code check the [Horizontal_Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Horizontal_Menus)